# Deploy a customed Alfresco

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, war, alfresco

I've customed my alfresco (classification plan, metadata, ...) and I wanted to know how to deploy this existing alfresco into a new one existing on other computer.

I think that I have to deploy my alfresco.war on the other computer in place on the existing alfresco.war and it's all ?

Thanks if you can help me !

Edit : I've tried to remplace the alfresco.war and share.war but it doesn't work.
If I produce a database dump that I restore on the new alfresco and I remplace the alf_data, do you think It can work ?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? If you've made interface changes you may also need to clear your browser history.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you've just about got it already. You need to:

1. Stop your tomcat instance.
2. Go to the tomcat/webapps directory in the Alfresco installation.
3. Delete the alfresco.war file. (taking a backup is always recommended)
4. Delete the alfresco directory.
5. Depending on the changes made delete the contents of the tomcat/temp and tomcat/work directories.
6. Start your tomcat instance.

Good practice is to package up your changes in to an amp and to deploy it using the [Alfresco Module Management Tool](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Module_Management_Tool) so you may want to look at doing that in future.

Comment: When I customed Alfresco thanks to graphical user interface, good-practice is also create an AMP or copying the alfresco.war is enough ?